# How to accumulate data over simulations in python

Tags: python, pytorch, simulation, data-analysis, montecarlo

I have a function `simulate`:

```
import torch

MAX_VALUE = 12
LENGTH, WIDTH = (120, 5)
MC_N = 100000

batch_size = 50

def simulate() -> tuple[npt.NDArray[np.int6], npt.NDArray[np.int16]]:
    x = torch.randint(low=0, high=MAX_VALUE, size=(batch_size, LENGTH, WIDTH), device="cpu")
    y = estimate(x, MC_N)
    return x, y
```

where `estimate` performs some slicing and torch-native operations like `.sum()` and `.std()` with few tensors of huge sizes `(batch_size, MC_N, <10, <10)`. Function simulate returns x of given shape and y of sizes `(batch_size, 7)`.

Then this function is run over `1_000_000 / MC_N` times using `multiprocessing.Pool` on 12 kernels. This takes about an hour of computation.

Note: I am using torch tensors instead of numpy ndarrays due to slight performance improvement, batch_size = 50 is chosen in the same way - it optimises whole execution time of program and batch_size > 500 almost exceeds my RAM limits.

I am wondering what is the best way to accumulate data, produced by simulate - tensors x and y, for future data analysis.

Expected size of x and y will be about `1_000_000 * (120 * 5 * sizeof(np.int16) + 7 * sizeof(np.int16)) ~ 10 Gb`, thus just appending results to some kind of buffer list is not an option. I am thinking about writing to csv/txt file, but I am worried about significant performance drop. As I said before, without any data collection it takes about an hour of work, I hope there is a way to collect data and don't double elapsed time.

Are there any best practices or advices for this type of task. Also I keep in mind possible migration to server with more RAM / kernels or even switching to GPU computations if 1_000_000 simulations won't be enough.

Comment: Large scientific data better be stored in known hierarchical binary data. Best way probably would be HDF5 or netcdf. On fast NVM drive 10GB should be reasonable